# Div width and height increase along with textarea content

Tags: jquery, html

Div increases with the text entered. Fine. But when I press enter height should increase according to the text size and also width shouldn't increase till the text reaches to the above width. Please help

http://jsfiddle.net/shabbirrangwala/NkRYY/8/

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
        $('.EDetailInset').css('height', ((this.value.length + 1) * 3) + 'px');
    }
    else {
        $('.EDetailInset').css('width', ((this.value.length + 1) * 11) + 'px');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Sorry but, aren't you [reinventing the wheel](http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin-version-2-0/)?

Comment: You could also use either of these plugins [TextAreaExpander (Demo)](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) and [autoResize Plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Comment: guys i think the OP also wants automatic horizontal scaling. the links that you guys posted are for vertical scaling only afais.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy Exactly. I want the div to react on text enter. horizontally and vertically both.

Comment: @above all: before i press enter i store a div width in a variable. When i press enter i want if condition to check if the width is equal to the above width if yes then start increasing width. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if it is working to expectation. Somehow you need to keep the width constant

```
var tWidth = $('textarea')[0].value.length;
var vWidth = 0;
var hIncr = 2; //initial line count - looks somehow?
var iheight = $('.EDetailInset').css('height').replace('px',''); //default height to height of box
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {



if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
$('.EDetailInset').css('height', (hIncr * iheight) + 'px'); //increase height by one line
  vWidth = 0; //so that the width does not increase
  hIncr++; //increase line number
}
else 
{

    vWidth = (vWidth+1);  //only this increase and reset to zero for new line
    if(vWidth*11 > tWidth) //if more characters than we had, increase box width
        tWidth = vWidth*11;
    console.log((vWidth*11)+':'+tWidth);

$('.EDetailInset').css('width', (tWidth) + 'px'); //no increment, width is static

}
});​
```

### [Check this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d54z/1/)

Comment: JSFiddle aint working man. Its directing me to my fiddle with no change?

Comment: Thanks. Its somewhat similar to what i need. But then there is still problem with your code that is when the enter is pressed 4-5 times div width stops increasing and on backspace it starts increasing again. just check. :)

Comment: have seen it too: it's a step forward and it aint there yet. You can trap the backscpace. The increasing with is problem of font calculation. The width of characters are not equal, simply doing `character*11` will not give you the exact width

Comment: I do not want the width to go outside maindiv. So am giving a limit to the width after which it should stop increasing. So when the width limit is reached i want keypress to stop performing and on enter press the typing on textarea should start. Can you answer?

Comment: am sorry I don't have enough time now but try this: `if(vWidth*11 > tWidth && vWidth*11 < maxWidth)` or do `if(vWidth*11 < maxWidth){ vWidth = (vWidth+1); }`. Either of these could help

Answer (score 1):

Although far from perfect, here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/V6BSY/2/

I have only tried to address the issue of horizontal scaling as a lot of other people have already showed how vertical scaling is done.

This also reduces back the size of the container when using backspace.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="txt">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#txt {
    background-color: rgba(208,228,254,0.3);
    border: 2px dashed #000000;   
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#txt textarea {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt").css("width", $("#txt textarea").css("width"));
});

$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {

    lines = $('#txt textarea').val().split('\n');
    maxLength = getLengthOfLongestLine(lines);

    var h = parseInt($(this).get(0).scrollHeight) + 5;
    var w = maxLength * parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));

    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
        $("#txt").css("height", h);
        $(this).css("height", h);        
    } else {
        $("#txt").css("width", w);
        $(this).css("width", w);        
    }

});

function getLengthOfLongestLine(arrLines) {        
    var maxLength = 0;
    for(var line in arrLines) {
        if (arrLines[line].length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = arrLines[line].length;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;                          
}
​
```

Comment: JSFiddle aint working man. Its directing me to my fiddle with no change?

Comment: Thanks man for the hard work. But still we gotta figure out that the width is increasing way too much.

Comment: not at all! yeah well :( i'd love to spend more time on it.. sadly have some stuff to handle :(.. but i guess we can build upon it and improve it perhaps

Comment: yeah sure bruv. Would love to see the updates from you. cheers.!

Answer (score -1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NkRYY/62/

```
// HTML
<div id="EDetail" class="EDetail EDetailText">
    <div class="EDetailInset" >
        <span style="font-size: 17px;">

        </span>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

// CSS
.EDetail, .EDetailDisabled {

    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: visible;    
    position: absolute;
}

.EDetail {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

}

.EDetailInset {
    background-color: rgba(217,247,217,0.3);
    font-size: 20px;
    height : 22px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(208,228,254,0.3);
    border: 2px dashed #000000;

    position: absolute;
    cursor: move;
    min-width:100px;

}





.EDetailText textarea, .EDetailText span {
    font: 100%/1.1 arial,sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
   padding: 5px;
}
.EDetailText textarea, .EDetailText textarea[disabled] {

    background: none repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    bottom: 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    left: 0px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 5px;
    resize: none;
    right: 6px;
    top: 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    width: 90%;
    overflow:auto;
}

//JS
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {


    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
    $('.EDetailInset').css('height', ((this.value.length + 10) * 3) + 'px');

    }
    //else
    //{
    //$('.EDetailInset').css('width', ((this.value.length + 10) * 11) + 'px');
    //}
    });
```

what's the limit width the time it reaches ?

Comment: Commenting out the width command is hardly answering this question.

Comment: Well, you posted this as an answer. But the only change I can see is that you removed the lines of jQuery that handled the width change. This does not address the OP's question...

Comment: Exactly Lix. Height is increasing according to what i need. But then i want the width also to increase on keyup. And when user press enter div width should stop increasing till the time text reaches the end.